# Using ParseQueryString function to get values from QueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I needed to get values out of a string in a QueryString format, that is such as: data1=value1&data2=value2...

Someone suggested I used HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to get the value, I've searched and searched but I can't find any documentation or implementation of this and the Microsoft documentation for it doesn't explain how it works, can someone tell me hwat I'm doing wrong, my code is below;

```
Public Shared Sub ProcessString(ByVal Vstring As String)
    Dim var As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Vstring)
    Dim vname As String = var.QueryString("VNAME")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) has an example.

```
' Parse the query string variables into a NameValueCollection.
Dim qscoll As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Vstring)
Dim vname As String = qscoll("VNAME")
```

A `NameValueCollection` represents a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

Comment: problem is NameValueCollection keeps coming up as not a valid data type do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @user1044220: Edited my answer to provide the full path to the class. You need to add `Imports System.Collections.Specialized` or use the  fully qualified name as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was referencing everything fine but I was doing it in a separate .VB dependency file, once I did it on the actual code behind of the aspx form that solved the problem and it all worked. So now I'm just passing the string from Codebehind as a specialised.NameValue collection in to the function.